# How to efficiently find dataframe row that contains items from list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, large-data

Let's say I have following example

```
items = ['milk', 'bread', 'water']

df:
name     item1    item2    item3

items_1  milk     water
items_2  milk     rubber   juice
items_3  juice    paper    wood
items_4  bread
items_5  bread    water    milk
items_6  milk     juice
```

In this example I would like to get all df rows whose members are completely in items list, which means:

- items_1
- items_4
- items_5

Now, the real "df" dataframe will contain several millions of rows, i.e. items_*, hence the "efficiently" in the title. The number of columns of "df" will be between 10 and 20. Also, there will be several thousands of "items" lists with between 10 and 20 elements.

Can someone please help me out on this one?

Comment: When you say completely in list, you mean milk, bread, water all have to be in the row correct?

Comment: Take items_1 row, check if every item in that row is also in the items list. in this case, milk and water are both in the items list (milk, bread, water) and that's the row that interests me.
Also, everything under items_4 row (just the bread in this case) is contained in the items list. Hope this clarifies the problem a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ~isin to check if the condition is NOT True for all the values, get the index, use boolean indexing. You get

```
true_names = df[~df.iloc[:, 1:].isin(items)].isnull().all(1)
df.loc[true_names, 'name']

0    name_1
3    name_4
4    name_5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried your proposal and it did speed up the execution time. Will try the other answers also to see if some solution is even faster then yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for item in dflist:
        if item not in items:
                print("this df list has an items that is not in the items list")
```

I know that the output isn't probably what you are looking to have as an output but your ideal output is unclear.

What this for loop does is it will cycle through each item in your df lists (ex. items_1, items_2, etc.). It will look at each item in this list and will check if it is in the list of items you are checking against.

If it finds an item that is not in the list of items you are checking against it will return that it has found an item not in your checking list. This seems what you are looking for, any value that is not in the first list of items labeled "items". So this checks for those and from here you could easily discard those.

Generally when searching a big data set, binary search is the way to go, however this does not seem that feasible in this situation unless you can put the df lists in alphabetical order, if you cannot I would do what I wrote above.

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

We need to find a way to affirm that the rows are completely in the `items` list, while still considering the null entries. A combination of [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html), [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) and [notna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) can help :

```
#set name as index
#allows us to focus on the items columns
#and later allows easy filtering
df = df.set_index("name")

#find rows that are in items
#and get the sum of the boolean
A = df.isin(items).sum(1)

#get the sum of rows
#that are not boolean
#this helps us narrow down
#items completely in the items list
#that are yet affected by null entries
B = df.notna().sum(1)

#compare A and B
#if they match, that implies complete entry in items list
cond = A.eq(B)

#let's see what cond looks : 

 cond

            name
items_1     True
items_2    False
items_3    False
items_4     True
items_5     True
items_6    False
dtype: bool

#filter df with condition to get your rows
df.loc[cond]


           item1    item2   item3
name            
items_1     milk    water   None
items_4     bread   None    None
items_5     bread   water   milk
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

If your dataframe looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = '''name     item1    item2    item3
items_1  milk     water
items_2  milk     rubber   juice
items_3  juice    paper    wood
items_4  bread
items_5  bread    water    milk
items_6  milk     juice'''

items = ['milk', 'bread', 'water']

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(txt))
df = df.fillna('').set_index('name')
print(df)
```

---

```
         item1   item2  item3
name                         
items_1   milk   water       
items_2   milk  rubber  juice
items_3  juice   paper   wood
items_4  bread               
items_5  bread   water   milk
items_6   milk   juice
```

You can do:

```
items = pd.Series(items + [''])
m = df.apply(lambda x: x.isin(items).all(), axis=1)
print(df[m])
```

Prints:

```
         item1  item2 item3
name                       
items_1   milk  water      
items_4  bread             
items_5  bread  water  milk
```